# Error in displaying mysql data in html using php ajax and json

Tags: php, ajax, json

This is my html :

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btnprimary">GENERATE</button>
  <div id="con">"Hello!"</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

and the ajax function is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#search").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"exhibitor_creator.php",
    data:data,
    dataType:"json",
 var id=data[0];
 var name=data[1];
 var mail=data[2];
 var pwd=data[3];
 $('#con').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> Name: </b>"+name+"<b> Mail Id:  
    </b>"+mail+"<b> Password: </b>"+pwd);
    });
    });   
    </script>
```

and my php is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "select * from add_exhibitor";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

I am trying to display the mysql data in html page using php, ajax and json.

First in html page when I click the generate button, I need to display the data which is already inserted in the `add_exhibitor` table. That I retrieved the data from `add_exhibitor` table in php also I encoded the data. Also I written an ajax function in the html page to display the data from php page. But its not working. Kindly tell me how to solve this

Comment: You say "its not working". What is it doing incorrectly? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Comment: No error messages. instead it simply displays the html page

Comment: @AnuKarthi  if i am understanding your question..you just want to append the value to html page (data from database).. Is it

Comment: Please edit your code so that it's easily read but mainly so that it doesn't contain errors. Now your ajax object doesn't have `success` property.

Comment: @AnuKarthi I suggest you to check for javascript errors through console window in your browser. It may help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "select * from add_exhibitor";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$rows = array();
$rows[] = $r;
echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the header function at the bottom of your code:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($rows);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an EventHandler like "onclick" so that when the button is clicked it calls the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, your php file gives result in **json** Format like

```
{"id":"1", "name": "anyname", "mail":"youremail", "password":"your password"}
```

Now,If i am understanding your problem, you want to append this data in your **html** file.
for this. **TRY these codes..**

**Your-html-filename.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="con">"Hello!"</div>

    <label for="" id="id"></label>
    <label for="" id="name"></label>
    <label for="" id="mail"></label>
    <label for="" id="password"></label>
    <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btnprimary">GENERATE</button>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>"></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>"></script>
</html>
```

now,Make another **js** file like

**data.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#search").on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-phpfilename.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(data)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(result,function(key,value){
                if(key === 'id')
                {
                    $("#id").append(value);
                }if(key === 'name')
                {
                    $("#name").append(value);
                }if(key === 'mail')
                {
                    $("#password").append(value);
                }if(key === 'password')
                {
                    $("#password").append(value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope, it will help you..!

Comment: will you please give all the files along with database file at dropbox..?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, your php file may give json result like this

```
    [{"id":"1", "name":"xxxx", "mail":"xxxx@yyy.com", "pwd":"123@#$ABC"}]
```

Please try these codes

**file_name.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"></script>
        <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="search" class="btn btnprimary" onclick="result()">GENERATE</button>
        <div id="con"><p>"Hello!"</p></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**myScript.js**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function result(){
    var len = $("#con p").length;
    $.get(
        'exhibitor_creator.php',
        function(data){
            if ( len == 1 ) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $( "#con" ).append("<p><b>ID:&nbsp;</b>" + data[key].id + "<b>&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;</b>" + data[key].name + "<b>&nbsp;Mail:&nbsp;</b>" + data[key].mail + "<b>&nbsp;Password:&nbsp;</b>" + data[key].pwd) + "</p>";
                })
            }
        },
        'json'
    );  
    }   
    </script>
```